# How to justify C postfix increment operator with precedence table?

Tags: c, increment, operator-precedence, postfix-operator

I am working with the C operator precedence table to better understand the operator precedence of C. I am having a problem understanding the results of the following code:

```
int a, b;
a = 1;
b = a++;   // does not seem to follow C operator precedence
```

Using the precedence table of C operators, I can not explain why with the postfix `++` operator, first the assignment is evaluated and then the increment.

The postfix increment operator (`++`) has the highest precedence in C and the assignment operator (`=`) has the lowest precedence. So in the above code first postfix `++` must executed and then assignment `=`. Therefore both variables `a` and `b` should equal 2 but they don't.

Why does the C operator precedence seems not to work with this code?

When doesn't the highest precedence of postfix `++` show itself?

Comment: In case this isn't clear, precedence and associativity are independent from order of evaluation. It's understandable how these terms can be confused though.

Comment: `a` is retrieved for the assignment, then the memory location of `a` is  incremented (not the retrieved value).

Comment: I think of the "post" in "postfix" as indicating that the increment occurs _after_ everything else is evaluated. i.e `char *str = "FreeBSD"; char increment() { ((*str++) + 1) }`, the pointer is de-referenced, the arithmetic is applied, and the value returned (in this case a 'G'.) Only then is the increment applied. This was helpful when I began grappling with things like Duff's Device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precedence happens during the *parsing*. It means that `++` applies to `a`, not to `b = a`.

But `++` means *post* incrementation, so performed *after* `a` is evaluated to be assigned to `b`

If you want both to take the value `2` perform a pre-incrementation:

```
b = ++a;
```

Answer (score 5):

This had nothing to do with precedence.  It's a matter of how the postfix `++` operator works.

The postfix `++` operator evaluates to the **current** value of its operand, *and* has the side effect of incrementing its operand.  In contrast the prefix `++` operator evaluates to the **incremented** value of its operand.

```
int a, b;
a = 1;
b = a++;   // b is 1, a is 2
b = ++a;   // b is 3, a is 3
```

This behavior of the postfix `++` operator is documented in section 6.5.2.4p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **The  result  of  the  postfix
>   `++` operator  is  the  value  of  the  operand.  As  a  side  effect,  the value of the operand object is incremented (that is, the value 1
>   of the appropriate type is added  to  it).**   See  the  discussions  of
>   additive  operators  and  compound  assignment  for information  on 
>   constraints,  types,  and  conversions  and  the  effects  of 
>   operations  on pointers.   The  value  computation  of  the  result 
>   is  sequenced  before  the  side  effect  of updating  the  stored 
>   value  of  the  operand.  With  respect  to  an 
>   indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of postfix
>   `++` is a single evaluation.  Postfix
>   `++` on an object with  atomic  type  is  a  read-modify-write  operation  with memory_order_seq_cst memory order semantics.

And the prefix `++` operator is documented in section 6.5.3.1p2:

> The value of the operand of the prefix
>   `++` operator is incremented.  **The result is the new value of the operand after incrementation.**  The expression
>   `++E` is equivalent to `(E+=1)` . See  the  discussions  of  additive  operators  and  compound  assignment  for  information  on
>   constraints, types, side effects, and conversions and the effects of
>   operations on pointers.

Answer (score 5):

Precedence *only* determines which operators are grouped with which operands during parsing.  It *does not* control order of evaluation. `++` having a higher precedence than `=` only means that `b = a++` is parsed as `b = (a++)` rather than `(b = a)++`.

The `++` operator (both unary and postfix forms) has a *result* and a *side effect*.  In the expression `b = a++`, the *result* of `a++` is the current value of `a` - that's what gets assigned to `b`.  The *side effect* of `a++` is to add 1 to `a`.

The order in which the assignment to `b` and the update to `a` occur is *unspecified*.  The most straightforward is

```
b <- a
a <- a + 1
```

but the following is also allowed:

```
tmp <- a
a <- a + 1
b <- tmp
```

The result of `++a` is the current value of `a` plus 1, and the side effect is to add 1 to `a`.  *Do not assume* that in an expression like `b = ++a` that `a` is updated before `b`.  Again, the order of evaluation could be something like

```
b <- a + 1
a <- a + 1
```

The actual evaluation order depends on your compiler, optimization settings, even the surrounding code.

The only operators that force left-to-right evaluation of expressions are the `&&`, `||`, `?:`, and comma operators.